# how to link mysql 'id' to html element

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database with some rows of data that display on a webpage. Now, I am looking for a way to link each 'ID' field in mysql to a button so that when the button is clicked, a php script will run that deletes the row of mysql information associated with that ID.

I know this is incorrect but I think its close. Just don't know about the php portion inside the id tag. Help?

```
<form action="remove.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Remove Entry" id="<?php $row['id'] ?>" />
</form>
```

Am I even on the right path?
Would remove.php look like...

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if($conn === false){
   die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "DELETE from newcars (stock, year, make, model, trim)
        WHERE ('$_POST[id] = $row[id]');

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Records deleted successfully.";
} 

else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysql_close($conn)
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Oh, why are you using `mysql_close` but `mysqli_*` everywhere else? **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Is this your actual code? there's some errors in there.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form action="remove.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (int)$row['id']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Remove Entry" />
</form>
```

You want to pass the ID in a form element, NOT with the submit button.

The PHP would look like this - and this is **more secure than your original code** as it uses prepared statements.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if($conn === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM newcars WHERE id = ?");
// prepare() can fail because of syntax errors, missing privileges, ....
if(false === $stmt) {
    // and since all the following operations need a valid/ready statement object
    // it doesn't make sense to go on
    // you might want to use a more sophisticated mechanism than die()
    // but's it's only an example
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}

$rc = $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
// bind_param() can fail because the number of parameter doesn't match the placeholders in the statement
// or there's a type conflict(?), or ....
if(false === $rc) {
    // again execute() is useless if you can't bind the parameters. Bail out somehow.
    die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$rc = $stmt->execute();
// execute() can fail for various reasons. And may it be as stupid as someone tripping over the network cable
// 2006 "server gone away" is always an option
if(false === $rc) {
    die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$stmt->close();

//redirect page back to view page
?>
```

Comment: Good job on `htmlspecialchars`, that's thorough.

Comment: No, I appreciate it. Few people pay attention to that. XSS is a serious issue I haven't had the energy to fight yet, too busy with SQL and crappy login systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Id be posted, it should be like this:

```
<form action="remove.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (int)$row['id']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Remove Entry" />
</form>
```

Post a hidden field with the name `id` and the value `$row['id']`.

And you should take care of the comments above to avoid mysql-injection in your php.

Comment: Good start but there's still a lot of issues in the PHP code as well.

Comment: @WheatBeak yes, but the question was only "how to send the id".